# Password encryption in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, encryption

How can I encrypt and decrypt passwords in C#? Thanks for any help.

Comment: explain more. do you really need to encrypt or just hashing would do the job? give us some context.

Comment: encrypting the given plain text to a encrypt value to store in database and 
decrypting the encrypted value to plain text.

Answer (score 10):

First, you're not actually going to save the encrypted password anywhere, rather you'd perform a one-way hash (e.g., [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions)) store that hash. Then when you challenge a user for his password, you perform the same hash. If the new hash matches the stored hash, you've got a match.

The difference between a hash and encryption is that with encryption, you can recover the original text, where with a hash you cannot.

Read up on SHA (Secure Hashing Algorithm) and other hashing algorithms. This should give you a good start.

Even better, learn about the built in [Membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx) in .NET. It's almost trivial to implement and it manages all that unpleasantness about userid's, passwords, logging in, logging out and a *lot* more for you.

Comment: good answer, except that MD5 should NOT be used for security related implementation anymore.

Comment: In the typical case you are correct, you'd generally store a password hash, but there are exceptions. I have an application where I store actual passwords.  It's a guest account system for our University.  Rather than expose passwords to our Help Desk staff I provide a way to reset a guest's password to the original if they have forgotten what they changed it to.  It stores these using reversible encryption in a database.  You can store encrypted anything as long as you keep the secret key, secret.

Comment: @Jaccco - what the heck was I thinking?! It's early. SHA, not MD5. Thanks for the tap. Edited accordingly

Comment: @Bob Kaufman - SHA-1 is close, theoretically, to be broken. There'll be another shift soon :D

Comment: @tvanfosson - You've sent me looking for a definitive article "why we hash rather than encrypt passwords", can't find it. I suppose it depends on the value of the account the password protects. I certainly wouldn't trust a financial institution that can recover my password.

Comment: @tvanfosson - here's a pretty good one, right in our collective backyard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it

Comment: -1 for lack of mentioning providing salt in the hash, +1 for mentioning not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You should use the BCrypt algorithm, not MD5 or SHA. BCrypt is designed to be slow, so bruteforce will take much longer time (you can actually set a strength per hash). Also the salt is stored with the hashed value, so you can't forget to use a salt.

Comment: +1 for mentioning SHA-1 being very close to broken.  SHA-2 is too close to SHA-1 algorithmically as well, so it should not be used in the long term if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

See this answer: [C# Password Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512909/c-sharp-password-encryption/6513914#6513914)

-- or --

Read this post: http://csharptest.net/470/another-example-of-how-to-store-a-salted-password-hash/

---

There is lots of good and bad information on the internet about storing passwords.  You need to know two things:

1. You should use a 'salted' hash to prevent dictionary attacks
2. You use at minimal the SHA256 hash provider

A quick search gave me this sample code:
http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx

and I'd go with this SaltedHash utility class (looks fairly complete at a glance):

http://www.dijksterhuis.org/creating-salted-hash-values-in-c/