# What is password hashing?

Tags: algorithm, hash, passwords

What does it mean to hash a password?

Comment: Couldn't you Google this? Could you expand your question? Are you looking at a source and not understanding something?

Comment: @Frank: I've come around on questions like these. Their lack of depth annoyed me too, but ignoring that, we can write a good landing page from Google for "password hashing".

Comment: @Michael, agreed.  Also, SO is building a reputation on being able to get your programming question answered quickly and accurately.  Which, in this case, perpetuates that reputation.

Comment: @Frank If you search for password hashing it's more likely you find Wikipedia than Stack Overflow. This one is just too simple.

Comment: A stackoverflow topic is on the second page of hits for password hashing as of 10/21/2009: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it

Comment: @Will And the Wikipedia page is the second link on the first page :)
(Not that it really matters)

Answer (score 16):

**Definition:**
[Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is the application of a function `f()` to a variable sized input to produce a constant sized output.

```
A => f() => X
B => f() => Y
C => f() => Z
```

A hash is also a one-way function which means that there isn't a function to reverse or undo a hash.  As well re-applying the hash `f(f(x))` isn't going to product `x` again.

**The Details:**

A hash function can be as simple as "add 13 to the input" or complex like a [Cryptographic Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) such as [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1).  There are many things that constitute a good hash function like:

- [Low Cost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Low_cost): Easy to compute
- [Deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Determinism): if I hash the input `a` multiple times, I am going to get the same output each time
- [Uniformity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity): The input will be evenly distributed among the possible outputs.  This falls in line with something called the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  Since there are a limited number of outputs we want `f()` to place those outputs evenly instead of in the same bucket.  When two inputs compute to the same output this is known as a collision.  It's a good thing for a hash function to produce fewer collisions.

**Hashing applied to Passwords:**

The hashing of passwords is the same process as described above, however it comes with some special considerations.  Many of the properties that make up a good hash function are not beneficial when it comes to passwords.

Take for example *determinism*, because hashes produce a deterministic result when two people use the same password the hash is going to look the same in the password store.  This is a bad thing!  However this is mitigated by something called a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

*Uniformity* on the other hand is beneficial because the desire is for the algorithm to limit collisions.

Because a hash is *One-Way* means the input cannot be determined from the output, which is why hashing is great for passwords!

Answer (score 15):

takes a block of data and returns a string such that you can't get your original block of data back.

[Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)

Hashing a password will take a clear text string and perform an algorithm on it (depending on the hash type) to get a completely different value.  This value will be the same every time, so you can store the hashed password in a database and check the user's entered password against the hash.

This **prevents** you from storing the **cleartext** passwords in the database (bad idea).

Here is a [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

Comment: I advise for this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Cryptographic_hash_algorithms
For password hashing there shoul be used only "cryptographic hash function" not for instance CRC

Answer (score 7):

A hash is simply a one-way function, that will take a string or data source and create an encrypted looking string.

There are various hashing algorithms the most popular is MD5, but there are many others. Many experts in the industry are using the SHA256 algorithm for better security.

MD5 Hash for the words:

password is 22e5ab5743ea52caf34abcc02c0f161d

PASSWORD is 319f4d26e3c536b5dd871bb2c52e3178

The character length of the result will be the same regardless of how many characters you try to hash. Hashes are commonly used to store passwords to prevent them from being viewed.