# c# MySQL reader not reading

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm develpoing a login server and i've come to this problem:
I'm using this SQL function to get password where username matches:

```
SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='someusername';
```

On c# i'm using this code:

```
string cmdString = ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='@username'");
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(CNN_STRING))
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdString, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();                
       }
```

On MySQL workbench it works normally but on c# i always get a null value, and if i try to use cmd.ExecuteReader and Reader.Read() instead of cmd.ExecuteScalar() i get a exception saying that i haven't run Reader.Read() though i did.

Comment: You shouldn't need to enclose @username in single-quotes; the parameterization should take care of that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put the parameter placeholder between single quotes. In this way your parameter placeholder becomes a literal string and thus there is no username named `'@username'`

```
string cmdString = ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=@username");
```

Said that, please be aware that storing passwords in plain text inside your database is a big security risk. You should store just the [hash of the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602776/what-is-password-hashing)

Comment: That was it, for some reason at the begining it wasn't working without quotes, now it does. And i am using password hashes.