# User authentication to database using .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication

I have a database created in SQL Server 2008 on my machine. It contains a table named login having two columns of username and password with certain values.

[This is my web service code](http://pastebin.com/JtW7aZkF) written in Visual Studio 2008. I need to check whether the user name and password I provide is correct or not i.e basically I want to authenticate the user via web service.

So can anyone tell me how should I can do that?

Comment: I hope none of your students are named [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Nope not at all. I m just not able to authenticate the user via the web service..can u tell me what has to be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would urge you to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) when dealing with SQL as to not be vulnerable to SQL Injection; especially for a public facing web service.
2. It appears from your queries you are storing passwords in [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext). Again, I would urge you to salt and [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782180/net-encryption/6782259#6782259) your user's passwords for better security.
3. You can accomplish what you are looking for by changing your query to a `COUNT(*)`, and executing as a scalar, and making sure the count is greater equal to one. Something like this:

   ```
   myCommand.CommandText = "select COUNT(*) from Login where Username = @Username AND Password = @HashedPassword";
   int rowCount = (int)mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
   return rowCount == 1 ? "success" : "bad username or password";
   ```

The `SqlDataReader` should be removed from your original code.

**EDIT**:
So what is this code doing?

We've changed the SQL Query slightly. I've also modified it to use parameters. So what this query is saying is *Get me the number of users that have this username and this password as an integer*.

So if one user has that username and password, it would return `1`. If no one had that username and password, it would return `0`.

`ExecuteScalar` is useful when you aren't expecting any rows back; just a single value. This is true in our case; all we are expecting is a number: the number of users.

So when you put all of this code together; it should look something like this:

```
try
{
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123"))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
            return (int) myCommand.ExecuteScalar() == 1 ? "success" : "bad username or password";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return "an error occurred.";
}
```

Comment: I am new to this . Can u explain what will the code u have given actually do ?

Comment: what should my GetLoginDetails method return if I use your code within it ?

Comment: @Parth_90: GetLoginDetails should return whatever you want it to return. If you want to return a magic string such as `success` and `failed`, that's up to you. You could also just return a boolean instead of a string as well.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the code ..But I m getting error in this line :   myCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;  ...the error says the name "username" doesn't exist in current context..

Comment: @Parth_90: I fixed my code if you want to re-copy and paste it. I mis-cased the variable names of `UserName` and `Password` from your original code.

Comment: @vcsjones let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1981/discussion-between-parth-90-and-vcsjones)