# What's wrong with these passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, passwords, sha256

When I try to put a new user's password into a MySQL database, it doesn't encrypt it correctly. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$encPassword = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']); 
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users(`userName`,`email`,`password`) 
        VALUES('%s','%s',PASSWORD('%s'))", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($encPassword))or die(mysql_error()); 
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
```

When I check the database though, it doesn't store the password as sha256 encrypted. It only has 16 random characters (it should have ~50). What's wrong with it?

Comment: is your field VARCHAR with proper length?

Comment: Of what type is your password field in the database?

Comment: I would recommend CHAR(64) or BINARY(256) instead. Not that it makes much of a difference, I suppose :)

Comment: @minitech it's stil a good practice, if you know you're always going to have the same number of characters. Plus, although it's not relevant here, you should get a speed-up if all your columns are fixed width (not relevant here b/c there's a varchar username and varchar email).

Comment: You should also salt your password for better security.  Using `bcrypt` to hash the password is better as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should use the PASSWORD keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in
>     MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For
>     that purpose, consider MD5() or SHA1() instead. Also see RFC 2195,
>     section 2 (Challenge-Response Authentication Mechanism (CRAM)),
>     for more information about handling passwords and authentication
>     securely in your applications.

But, you've already hashed the password on the 1st line of code. Just insert that directly into the database...

Comment: sha256 is a *hash* function, not an encryption algorithm. Hash algorithms are designed to be one-way, ie. non-reversible. You should edit your answer to say "hashed", not "encrypted".

Comment: I've changed it to be more specific. But in my defense 'encrypted' is not wrong -- hashing is just a specific type of encryption.

Comment: I have to disagree (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it). Hashing and encryption are both in the realm of *cryptography*, but they are fundamentally different. Hashing is irreversible, while encryption, by definition, must be two-way. There must exist a decryption function for every encryption function.

Answer (score 4):

Check you have correct column lenght allowed in your table. That's the most common problem. Your field must be at least `VARCHAR(64)`

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that the OP was using `PASSWORD` which stores the result in 41 characters according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password. Nevermind :P

Comment: @minitech: it doesn't matter, he can use 64, too, it won't kill him :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of `$encPassword` before the `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `PASSWORD('%s')` function in your query, (so you are double hashing your password).

Just insert it as other values (`'%s'`)