# Encrypting passwords in database by using SHA-256 algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, sha, message-digest

I'd would like to encrypt in a database the password by using SHA-256 algorithm. I have made some researches and I found out I should use `MessageDigest`class to encrypt properly a string object. The problem is how should revert the hash function to get back to the original password? I mean If I would create a login system, I have to be able to get back to the original password or maybe not? Maybe when the password is filled into the form, it has to be converted into hash function and compared to the hash string stored in database, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decrypt SHA-256 encrypted String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brother, the entire purpose of hashes is that you should not be able to get the original string back from them. What you need to do in case of passwords is you hash the user input and compare it with the hash of the password to check if it was the original password. To know how you convert the password into a SHA-256 hash read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-encode-some-string-with-sha256-in-java).

Comment: Thank you Adbul Fatir. I asked it only to be safer