# Java AES with de-hashing

Tags: java, encryption, hash, aes

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to do de-hashing with salt.

Because currently I using doing encrypt with salt and hash. But I want to study about de-hashing part, is it possible to do de-hashing ?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string

Comment: AES is an encryption algorithm which has nothing to do with hashing. Are you talking about deriving the key for AES through hashing of a password?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that by *de-hashing*, you mean reversing the hashing process.

Hashing is a form of one way encryption. The original message is entirely destroyed in the process of creating the hash and, therefore, it is not possible to reverse the process. If it *is* possible, then that is a problem with the hashing algorithm.

Or in more formal terms, Hashing algorithms, by definition, are not [Bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).