# How to do login using jmeter, where entered username and password both are in encrypted mode

Tags: encryption, jmeter, sha256

I'm trying to do login to my site using `jmeter` tool.

But when I entered a valid username and password and press the submit button, inside the browser you can check that one post request is getting fired with cryptographic values.

So, due to cryptographic values of username and password. I am not able to do login to the site.

**Note:** `SHA-256` algorithm is used for cryptographic.

For more details on this issue, please refer below mentioned image.

[image]

So, can anyone help me how do I able to do login to my site?

Comment: SHA-256 is not encryption, it is a cryptographic hash.

Comment: @zaph, thanks for your valuable comment, can you please help me to get login with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can hash your expected (regular) value with Sha256 because you **can't decrypt** it, See [decrypt sha256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string)

> SHA-256 is a cryptographic (one-way) hash function, so **there is no**
>   **direct way to decode it**. The entire purpose of a cryptographic hash
>   function is that you can't undo it.

You can add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following sha256 conversion which put value in variable:

```
String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex("myPassword");
vars.put("myPassword", sha256hex);
```

and then you can use variable `${myPassword}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried above code, but it is not working for me.

Comment: It's working in Jmeter 3.1/3.2 What's not working exactly?

Comment: I am using `Jmeter 3.0` and above code is not getting encrypted value.

Comment: You can hash your expected (regular) value with Sha256. You can't decrypt it, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string