# Is there any method to convert a SHA256 hash string to a Java string?

Tags: java, android, sha256

I have the following code and I want a Java string from a SHA256 hash string. Is there a way to convert hex string to its original value?

```
public class CryptoHash {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-256" );
        String text = "Text to hash, cryptographically.";

        // Change this to UTF-16 if needed
        md.update( text.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) );
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        String hex = String.format( "%064x", new BigInteger( 1, digest ) );
        System.out.println( hex );
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't a hash exactly meant to be impossible to convert back to original string?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to get your original string back from the hash, or the `[]byte` (digest) from the outputted hex string?

Comment: i want to convert an outputted hex string to ASCII

Comment: how do you want to convert for example 0xFF to [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCIIhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt SHA-256 encrypted String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316437/how-to-decrypt-sha-256-encrypted-string)

Comment: for example from "f56c3a71b29e28ce7bc8f2f3f1ede0f89a40b25a8857b2bc25023a40a7391fb8" to ASCII

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to revert a SHA-256 hashed string back into it's original form. This is not possible, as the SHA-256 hashing function is a so called one-way hash. You can only turn a string into a hashed string, you cannot turn the hashed string back into a normal, readable string.

Comment: i have a code to convert hex to ASCII but i am not getting expected output. the code returning ASCII value as õl:q²(Î{Èòóñíàø@²ZW²¼%:@§9¸

Comment: ok so how do you want to convert the first `0xf5` to [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/)? or you mean "Extended ASCII"?

Comment: `hash` itself is designed **exactly** to make it impossible to get original value from it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i am pretty sure (maybe i'm wrong) that OP is 
aware of fact that if the original data has for example 10MB and the hash code has 32 bytes it is impossimble to get that 10MB bask from 32 bytes... he probably wants to convert that hex string to 32 binary bytes - for example: "566c6164" is `Vlad` in ASCII

Comment: @pskink i just edited my question..is there any solution?

Comment: @Greggz my problem is somewhat different.

Comment: If this is the case, the title is either wrong or ambiguous.

Comment: @ProgFroz i thought like i have a code for hash password with salt. after that i need to convert it to hex to ASCII

Comment: @pskink looks like you are right

Comment: I am afraid that my answer is still the same. When you convert the Hash into Hex and then to ASCII you will find that you simply got your Hash back.

Comment: maybe http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Givenahexstringthiswillreturnthebytearraycorrespondingtostring.htm ?

Comment: @pskink thank you..but my expected output is somewhat different..

Comment: different? meaning what?

Comment: @pskink i tried that method but getting unexpected output for hash hex

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Maybe you are looking at converting a byte array to base64 (as your base64 code seems to do)? In that case, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418485/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-base64-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer: No, there is no way.

Longer Answer: There may be a way using a Brute Force Strategy. But it would take a long time, too long to be efficient.

See, Hash in general is made to make it impossible to reverse. You convert the String into some Hash and this cannot be reversed.
You may take a look at how Hashes and Encrypting work.

https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/how-does-a-hashing-algorithm-work/

If it would be that easy, using just one line of code, the whole idea and process of hashing would be problematic.

Edit: If you want to convert a String to Hash, then to Hex and finally to ASCII your result will be the original Hash. Therefore, the idea won't work out. You cannot decrypt it this way.