# encryption and decryption of values using sha2 in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to encrypt a value and sending it through the URL. How do I encrypt and decrypt passwords or any value using the `sha2()` function in PHP?

please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `sha2` is an **hashing** algorithm and goes only one way!

Comment: so how do i do the encription and the decryption? @Matteo Tassinari

Comment: @UtkarshSingh You *don't* with a hash function. The linked questions/answers explains why.

Comment: Another useful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it

Answer (score 2):

You can't decrypt password encrypted using sha2. You can encrypt value which user entered in form and compare it with this stored in ex. mysql database.

Comment: Arg, *why did you say ["encrypt"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)?* Incorrect terminology started - and perpetuates - this whole genre of question! Hashing is *not* encryption.

Comment: @user2864740 You're right, my mistake.