# Laravel 5.8 - save user emails encrypted

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, encryption

I'm looking for a way to encrypt the user emails in the database. Since Encrypt always generates a different string, it fails.
So I took sha1.

in AuthenticatesUsers I've changed the credentials method to:

```
 protected function credentials(Request $request)
 {
    return ['email' => sha1(strtolower($request->email)), 'password' => ($request->password)];
 }
```

This works great for the login/registration. But there are problems with resetting the password.

Resetting the password uses the SendsPasswordResetEmails trait.

There it this credentials method:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('email');
}
```

This always fails, cause it does not find the user (cause the user is saved with sha1 email)

if I change it to `return ['email' => sha1(strtolower($request['email']))];`

I get the error, that the email is not in the right RFC standart, to send a email. The Problem is, I don't really find the place, where laravel is searchig for the user with this email. Anyway, I don't really have a clue, how I can solve this problem at all.

I want to encrypt the email itself, because in germany there is a law which forces us to store personal data encrypted, like the email.

Answer (score 6):

First thing to say is that **Hashing** is not the same as **Encryption**.

**Encryption** is a *two way* function, that is if you can *encrypt* an email you can *decrypt* it with a *reverse* function, if you know the *encryption key*, and obtain the original email.

**Hashing** is a *one way* function, that is if you *hash* a password you **can't** obtain the original password with a reverse function, you can only *verify* that, when you input the password again, the hash you obtain matches the original hash, so you only know that the two password are identical.

You usually store password **hashed**, not **crypted**, so even the administrator can't recover the original password, he con only verify that a input from a user has a hash that match the original password he entered.

You can read more in this stackoverflow question: [Difference between Hashing a Password and Encrypting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it).

The `sha1()` is a *hashing* function, so is not reversable, you **can't** obtain the original email.

Laravel has the functions `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` to encrypt things, see the [docs on encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption), and has the functions `Hash::make()` to hash a password and `Hash::check()` to verify the password, see the [docs on hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing).

So if you want to **encrypt** the emails, not hashing them with sha1, you should use `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`.

The best way for you is to use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators), i.e.:

```
public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    return decrypt($value);
}

public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['email'] = encrypt($value);
}
```

So you will have email encrypted in the database and you can use `$user->email` in your code.

But I have to warn you that with encrypted email the login process is irreparably **broken**, you have to use another *unique field* like `username` for the **login**, not the email, so in your login controller you have to write:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: Okay. I've tried that. If I register a new user I encrypt the user email. Now in AuthenticatesUsers.php credentials method, I do a return 'email' => decrypt($request->email) ... - which is only giving me a "The payload is invalid.
"

Comment: of course, $request->email is the normal email. without any encryption. So this can't work. I don't know where the login is calling for the user, so I can check the email there.

Comment: You can use mutators, so you don't have to worry where to encrypt or decrypt in your code, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I've used the mutators. Also I did all changes which was neccessary to use the username. I can now login with username and so on. Still, if I want to reset the password, laravel auth is trying to get the email, which is still encrypted. I don't really understand why laravel is not decrypting the email, cause I have the decrypt email attribute mutator in my user model

Comment: Okay, I've found the error. In my user factory for test users, i'm encrypting the emails. But since I have this mutator which is also encrypting a email if it get's set. The email was encrypted twice. Thats why the decrypt, wasn't able to decrypt it properly.

Comment: since I've removed the encrypt from the factory and only the user mutator is still there, it works

Comment: Yes, you have to use enc/decrypt only in the mutators. Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it works.