# Password encryption spring boot mvc using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, encryption, passwords

I want to use password encryption before it will be saved in mySQL. For this school project, i am using Spring boot mvc together with hibernate. What is the best and simplest way to do it? I am new to Java, spring boot, hibernate.
Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bcrypt hashing instead of encyption.
 Check differece between hashing and encryption [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it)

1. You need to create bean of BcryptPasswordEncoder

   @Bean
   BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
2. Now autowire the bcrypt bean

   @Autowired
   private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
3. Use the bcryptencoder to ecode the password before saving to
   database

   User user = new User();
   user.setUserName("username");
   user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("userpassword"));

So the, overall code

```
//class that handles saving/registering
public class UserRegister{

        @Autowired
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private userRepository userRepository; 

        public void register() {
            User user = new User();
            user.se`enter code here`tUserName("username");
            //encodes the password
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("userpassword"));
            //saves to database
            userRepository.save(user);
        }

}
```