# Incorrect Syntax near '='

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

i watched a course and the teacher write this code and its worked for him but shows me this error..
my CODE

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Admin set 
 username=@username.password=@password.Fullname=@Fullname")
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textuser.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textpassword.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", textFullname.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Error In This Line...
 con.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("DELETED");
 upload_data_into_GridView_from_database();
}
```

Comment: `update Admin set username=@username, password=@password, Fullname=@Fullname where id=@id`

Comment: btw, I like that after password update user will get message "DELETED"

Comment: Suggested reading: [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing an e, in ExecuteNonQuery:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also instead of a . you need a comma  (,) on your update query:

Answer (score 4):

The dots in the query should be commas instead. And as far as your code is concerned, the query seems to be missing a `where` clause to filter on `id` (or the-like):

I would suggest:

```
update admin
set username = @username, password = @password, Fullname = @Fullname
where id = @id
```