# TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined. Using CypherJS in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptojs

I wanted to use some kind of encoding for my web app, because when I saw today, that my password is visible to a naked eye in network tab in DevTools, I thought I would get a heart palpitations or some s**t. I used CryptoJS because it was the first thing that popped me up in the browser.
I started rewriting my code and when I saw some bugs I tried to fix 'em, but this one, is the buggiest bug ever. I googled it, and saw nothing that actually concern me. So I came here and I ask you what actually is going on.
Here's some code:

**Code that compilator think is wrong**

```js
var key = this._keyPriorReset = this._key;
var keyWords = key.words;
var keySize = key.sigBytes / 4;
```

**Code that I think is wrong**

```js
import { Component } from 'react'
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
import doesSesVarExist from '../doesSesVarExist'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';

require('dotenv').config();

export default class Info extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      theme: 'dark',
      profpic: '../profpic/default.png'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(!doesSesVarExist('username') || !doesSesVarExist('password')){
      window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/account/login'
    }
    if(doesSesVarExist('theme')){
      this.setState({
        theme: ReactSession.get('theme')
      })
    }else{
      if(doesSesVarExist('username') && doesSesVarExist('password')){
        axios.post('/api/get_theme', {
          username: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(document.getElementById('username').value), process.env.ENCRYPTSECRETKEYUSERNAME),
          password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(document.getElementById('password').value), process.env.ENCRYPTSECRETKEYPASSWORD)
        }).then(response => {
          ReactSession.set('theme', response.data.theme)
          this.setState({
            theme: response.data.theme
          })
        })
      }else{
        ReactSession.set('theme', 'dark')
        this.setState({
          theme: ReactSession.get('theme')
        })
      }
    }

    axios.post('/api/get_profpic', {
      username: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ReactSession.get('username')), process.env.ENCRYPTSECRETKEYUSERNAME),
      password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ReactSession.get('password')), process.env.ENCRYPTSECRETKEYPASSWORD)
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({ 
        profpic: response.data
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(!document.body.classList.contains(this.state.theme)){
      document.body.classList.remove('dark')
      document.body.classList.remove('light')
      document.body.classList.add(this.state.theme)
    }

    const onLogoutClick = () => {
      ReactSession.set('username', undefined)
      ReactSession.set('password', undefined)
      window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/account/login'
    }

    return(
      <div id="userinfo">
        <img src={'../' + this.state.profpic}></img>
        <p>{ReactSession.get('username')}</p>
        <div class={this.state.theme} onClick={() => onLogoutClick()}>Log out</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? If so, then the password being visible in the request is normal, and you don't need any extra encryption since HTTPS requests are already encrypted. If not, then you should switch to HTTPS.

Comment: Since you'll need to share the key to the client-side somehow (and your current method is wrong since `process.env` doesn't exist on the browser), and any secure method of doing so is just going to be reimplementing TLS, but worse.

Comment: I totally agree with @SuperStormer. You do not need to add a third party module for this purpose.

Comment: TLDR: [don't roll your own crypto stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own), use the crypto stack (TLS) already designed for this purpose.

Comment: Actually, I use HTTP but I don't want to switch to HTTPS, I want to encrypt the password because I want it to be also encrypted in my database

Comment: Ok, so I will learn sth about the mysterious 'TLS' and see what I can do here

Comment: First of all, [passwords in databases should be hashed, not encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it), unless you're writing a password manager or something that requires passwords to be decrypted for some reason.

Comment: Secondly, [client-side hashing/encryption is bad](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53594/why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so-uncommon)

Comment: Note: TLS is just the crypto protocol that HTTPS uses, ie. HTTPS = HTTP plus TLS