# How to create a local storage for a python desktop application?

Tags: python, database, tkinter, local-storage, local-database

i want to create a desktop application that will take an input (email and password) and store it for later use in my tkinter app. How can i store this data in a secure way on the user's end so on their laptop locally  where i can access it every time the user opens the application it will auto sign them in. i don't want to create a server on my end or make a website or a database.

i just want to store the data locally with python and have access to it in a secure way.

thx in advanced :)

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"?  You can create a file in whatever directory contains the executable, in one of a dozen different formats (INI, JSON, plain text, sqlite3).  You can't make it unreadable, since they'll have your source code as well.

Comment: Tkinter runs on the user's computer, not a server.

Comment: "secure" from whom?  It's hard to keep data completely secure from someone who has full access to the stored data and the code you're using to decrypt it.

Comment: so should i store it in a pickle  file and use it ?

Comment: research sqlite

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the data:

```py
import json
data = {"username":"username","password":"123"}
with open('data.json', 'w+') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Open the data

```py
import json
with open("data.json") as file:
  data = json.load(file)
```

this will save all the stuff in the `data` dictionary and you'll be able to access it from a file called `data.json` in the same directory of the python file.

Comment: thx, but regarding the password i want to encrypt it then decrypt it, what would u suggest ?

Comment: I think you mean `hashing` not `encrypting` they're 2 different things. Passwords are usually hashed then to check the validity you hash the input and compare both. I suggest looking into a module called `hashlib` in python for hashing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it

Comment: but since i want to get its value again i can decrypt it but can't dehash it

Comment: Yes you're not supposed to "dehash". if you want to check if a password is write then you could just hash the input and see if both hashes match.